# Owl Carousel Can't Loop in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7, slider, carousel, slideshow, owl-carousel

i have drupal website that using Owl Carousel v1.3.2 for it slideshow slider. but the slider can't loop, when i comes to the end of image,it rewind to first image while showing the previous image. I have tried to put `loop : true` in it js code but doesnt work.
anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to loop, you need to edit the settings for your carousel at:

```
[your site]/admin/config/user-interface/owlcarousel
```

Select the settings group that is being applied to your carousel.

Check the box next to "Rewind Nav" in the settings.
[image: See image below]

I had the same problem and this fixed it for me.